# Extract items from pulldown menu in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to extract the contents of a pulldown menu in excel.  These are the attributes from Amazon offers sellers to list an item.

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/btg/electronics_browse_tree_guide.xls

The problem is that data fields are grayed out & even after I unlock the spreadsheet I can't seem to get access to the part that stores the lists.  Can I extract the contents using any software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the drop down in the `Refinements` sheet.

These values are being populated from a hidden sheet called `DB`. Just right click on any of the bottom tabs and select "Unhide."

You can also do this through the VBE (Alt + F11), selecting the sheet and then changing the "Visible" drop down.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know.  If I had the reputation, I'd upvote this comment! :)